# Crystal Report Script To Find Title of Max Value?(simple Q!)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, reporting, report

Please Help!
I asked my Q in many Forums but i did'nt recieve any clear answer.
This is my Q:

I created a table in a Details Section and I have a Title Col and Point Col in this table how can I write code to find Title of max point in my table???
this is my .rpt overview:
[image]
<sub>(source: [googlepages.com](http://mahdiahmadirad.googlepages.com/2009-08-28_222537.png))</sub>

you see i have 3 cols in Details Section. Point,BitParagonTitle,Alphabet.
I want to show BitParagonTitle to user according to Maximum of point in footer of report.
How can I perform this in Crystal report? please Help me!!!
So I want to:

1. Find Maximum Value of point Column.
2. Find title of Max Point.

   I created a collection of Data Object in an ArrayList as report DataSource.
   **Please Help me to write some crystal report scripts to find Title of Max Point and show it in Group Footer.**

   *This is Important that I dont use SQL DB Procedures or tables as data source and I Collected  Data manually as I said.*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of all of your requirements, but if you don't mind the Details being sorted the easiest way is to group by the Point column and then if the points are sorted ascending you can simply put the field title and point fields in the Point group footer. This will only display the last row of the Point column which in turn will be the maximum since it is sorted asc.

This will give you the maximum row so if you didn't care to see the other rows you can simply suppress the details section. Hope this makes sense and helps.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a pair of global Crystal variables in a formula that is evaluated in the Details section, as well as two other formulas referring to those variables.
The two variables are to store the max of point, and the title associated with that (so presumably a NumberVar and a StringVar, say called MaxPoint and MaxPointTitle).
One formula goes in the Report Header, and simply initialises the two variables to zero and empty string.
The second goes in the Details section. It evaluates if the current Point value is higher than that stored in the MaxPoint variable. If so, it stores the new value in MaxPoint and the current title in MaxPointTitle.
In the Report footer, a third formula is used to display the title and/or value.
If you want group max values rather than overall ones, move the formula in the Report header to the Group header, and from the Report footer to the Group footer, and it should work.

Comment: tnx.Your answer is best solution for that.But there is a problem with me.I am not Familiar with Crystal Formula Scripts and dont know how to write it syntaxically!! Can You help me to write code for your solution.I used an "UnboundNumber1" in details and "UnboundNumber2" for MaxPoint in header and "UnboundString1" for Title of MaxPoint in Group Header.These are Suppressed, and a "UnboundString1" for Title of MaxPoint in Group Footer. thsi is visible.I wrote this for "UnboundNumber1" in "Edit Formula": if {ReportObj.Point}>{@UnboundNumber2} then {@UnboundNumber2} := {ReportObj.Point} but error!